# Why is SQL text-based?

Tags: sql, exec, sql-injection, object-oriented-database

I suppose this isn't a particularly "good fit for our Q&A format" but no idea where else to ask it.

Why is SQL-querying *text* based? Is there a historical motivation, or just laziness?

```
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name=$name");
```

It opens up an incredible number of stupid mistakes like above, encouraging SQL injection. It's basically `exec` for SQL, and `exec`'ing code, especially dynamically generated, is widely discouraged.
Plus, to be honest, prepared statements seem like just a verbose workaround.

Why don't we have a more object-oriented, noninjectable way of doing it, like having a directly-accessible database object with certain methods:

```
$DB->setDB("mysite");
$table='users';
$col='username';
$DB->selectWhereEquals($table,$col,$name);
```

Which the database itself *natively* implements, completely eliminating all resemblance to `exec` and nullifying the entire basis of SQL injection.

Culminating in the real question, is there any database framework that does anything like this?

Comment: historically, all the languages were text based... nowadays you can devise other methods, but in that time this was the only viable option.

Comment: Better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "is there any database framework that does anything like this" - yes. there are *many*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are programming languages text-based? Quite simply: because text can be used to represent powerful human-readable/editable DSLs ([Domain-specific language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)), such as SQL.

The better (?) question is: *Why do programmers refuse to use placeholders?*

Modern database providers (e.g. ADO.NET, [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) support placeholders and an appropriate range of database adapters<sup>1</sup>. Programmers who fail to take advantage of this support only have themselves to blame.

Besides *ubiquitous support for placeholders* in direct database providers, there are also *many* different APIs available including:

- "Fluent database libraries"; these generally map an AST, such as [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), onto a dynamically generated SQL query and take care of the details such as correctly using placeholders.
- A wide variety of [ORMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping); may or may not include a fluent API.
- Primitive CRUD wrappers as found in the [Android SQLite API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), which looks suspiciously similar to the proposal.

I *love* the power of SQL and *almost none of the queries I write can be expressed in such a trivial API*. Even LINQ, which is a powerful provider, can sometimes get in my way (although the prudent use of Views helps).

---

<sup>1</sup> Even though SQL is text-based (and such is used to pass the *shape* of the query to the back-end), bound data need not be included in-line, which is where the issue of SQL Injection (being able to change the *shape* of the query) comes in. The database adapter can, and does if it is smart enough, use the API exposed by the target database. In the case of SQL Server this amounts to sending the data separately [via RPC] and for SQLite this means creating and binding separate prepared-statement objects.